# How to get multiple strings from same JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, string

I have that JSON code (http://pastebin.com/TjjJ4jWk), he has 10 summonerId

(formatted version)

```
{
    "gameId" : 467366059,
    "mapId" : 11,
    "gameMode" : "CLASSIC",
    "gameType" : "MATCHED_GAME",
    "gameQueueConfigId" : 4,
    "participants" : [{
            "teamId" : 100,
            "spell1Id" : 4,
            "spell2Id" : 14,
            "championId" : 157,
            "profileIconId" : 588,
            "summonerName" : "MEDAUMASKINCOPY",
            "bot" : false,
            "summonerId" : 2833743,
            "runes" : [{
                    "count" : 6,
                    "runeId" : 5247
                }, {
                    "count" : 3,
                    "runeId" : 5251
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5289
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5317
                }, {
                    "count" : 1,
                    "runeId" : 5337
                }, {
                    "count" : 2,
                    "runeId" : 5412
                }
            ],
            "masteries" : [{
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4111
                }, {
                    "rank" : 4,
                    "masteryId" : 4112
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4122
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4131
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4132
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4134
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4141
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4142
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4144
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4152
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4162
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4211
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4212
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4221
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4222
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4232
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "teamId" : 100,
            "spell1Id" : 11,
            "spell2Id" : 4,
            "championId" : 254,
            "profileIconId" : 550,
            "summonerName" : "copy",
            "bot" : false,
            "summonerId" : 2883696,
            "runes" : [{
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5247
                }, {
                    "count" : 3,
                    "runeId" : 5290
                }, {
                    "count" : 6,
                    "runeId" : 5295
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5315
                }, {
                    "count" : 3,
                    "runeId" : 5335
                }
            ],
            "masteries" : [{
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4111
                }, {
                    "rank" : 4,
                    "masteryId" : 4113
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4122
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4131
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4132
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4134
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4141
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4142
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4152
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4162
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4213
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4214
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4222
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4224
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4232
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "teamId" : 100,
            "spell1Id" : 4,
            "spell2Id" : 12,
            "championId" : 85,
            "profileIconId" : 23,
            "summonerName" : "Yzy Zikaa",
            "bot" : false,
            "summonerId" : 1356728,
            "runes" : [{
                    "count" : 1,
                    "runeId" : 5273
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5297
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5317
                }, {
                    "count" : 3,
                    "runeId" : 5357
                }, {
                    "count" : 8,
                    "runeId" : 5402
                }
            ],
            "masteries" : [{
                    "rank" : 4,
                    "masteryId" : 4112
                }, {
                    "rank" : 4,
                    "masteryId" : 4113
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4123
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4131
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4133
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4143
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4152
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4154
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4162
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4211
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4212
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4213
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4222
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4232
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "teamId" : 100,
            "spell1Id" : 7,
            "spell2Id" : 4,
            "championId" : 104,
            "profileIconId" : 608,
            "summonerName" : "Gunex",
            "bot" : false,
            "summonerId" : 653768,
            "runes" : [{
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5245
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5290
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5317
                }, {
                    "count" : 3,
                    "runeId" : 5335
                }
            ],
            "masteries" : [{
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4111
                }, {
                    "rank" : 4,
                    "masteryId" : 4112
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4121
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4122
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4131
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4132
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4134
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4142
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4152
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4162
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4211
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4213
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4221
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4222
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4232
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "teamId" : 100,
            "spell1Id" : 4,
            "spell2Id" : 3,
            "championId" : 117,
            "profileIconId" : 660,
            "summonerName" : "uunk",
            "bot" : false,
            "summonerId" : 633003,
            "runes" : [{
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5273
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5298
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5316
                }, {
                    "count" : 3,
                    "runeId" : 5357
                }
            ],
            "masteries" : [{
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4211
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4212
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4221
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4222
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4232
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4311
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4312
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4313
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4322
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4324
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4331
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4334
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4341
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4342
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4353
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4362
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "teamId" : 200,
            "spell1Id" : 14,
            "spell2Id" : 4,
            "championId" : 25,
            "profileIconId" : 585,
            "summonerName" : "Zigoto",
            "bot" : false,
            "summonerId" : 458902,
            "runes" : [{
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5273
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5289
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5317
                }, {
                    "count" : 3,
                    "runeId" : 5357
                }
            ],
            "masteries" : [{
                    "rank" : 4,
                    "masteryId" : 4113
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4121
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4123
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4131
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4133
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4134
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4143
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4152
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4154
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4162
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4312
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4313
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4322
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4324
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4334
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "teamId" : 200,
            "spell1Id" : 4,
            "spell2Id" : 11,
            "championId" : 60,
            "profileIconId" : 28,
            "summonerName" : "TakeruX",
            "bot" : false,
            "summonerId" : 1513707,
            "runes" : [{
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5289
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5317
                }, {
                    "count" : 3,
                    "runeId" : 5357
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5402
                }
            ],
            "masteries" : [{
                    "rank" : 4,
                    "masteryId" : 4113
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4114
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4123
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4124
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4133
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4134
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4143
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4152
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4154
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4162
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4213
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4214
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4222
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4224
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4232
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "teamId" : 200,
            "spell1Id" : 4,
            "spell2Id" : 12,
            "championId" : 150,
            "profileIconId" : 518,
            "summonerName" : "52GO Jabiraka",
            "bot" : false,
            "summonerId" : 531086,
            "runes" : [{
                    "count" : 8,
                    "runeId" : 5245
                }, {
                    "count" : 1,
                    "runeId" : 5251
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5289
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5317
                }, {
                    "count" : 1,
                    "runeId" : 5335
                }, {
                    "count" : 2,
                    "runeId" : 5343
                }
            ],
            "masteries" : [{
                    "rank" : 4,
                    "masteryId" : 4113
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4114
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4122
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4132
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4211
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4213
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4221
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4222
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4232
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4233
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4234
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4243
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4244
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4252
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4262
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "teamId" : 200,
            "spell1Id" : 4,
            "spell2Id" : 7,
            "championId" : 18,
            "profileIconId" : 718,
            "summonerName" : "Reed x",
            "bot" : false,
            "summonerId" : 891096,
            "runes" : [{
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5245
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5289
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5317
                }, {
                    "count" : 3,
                    "runeId" : 5337
                }
            ],
            "masteries" : [{
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4112
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4114
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4122
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4124
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4131
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4132
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4134
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4141
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4142
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4144
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4151
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4152
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4162
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4211
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4212
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4221
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4222
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4232
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "teamId" : 200,
            "spell1Id" : 4,
            "spell2Id" : 3,
            "championId" : 267,
            "profileIconId" : 610,
            "summonerName" : "SK Sheldon",
            "bot" : false,
            "summonerId" : 2982516,
            "runes" : [{
                    "count" : 1,
                    "runeId" : 5251
                }, {
                    "count" : 8,
                    "runeId" : 5257
                }, {
                    "count" : 9,
                    "runeId" : 5297
                }, {
                    "count" : 5,
                    "runeId" : 5315
                }, {
                    "count" : 4,
                    "runeId" : 5317
                }, {
                    "count" : 1,
                    "runeId" : 5345
                }, {
                    "count" : 2,
                    "runeId" : 5357
                }
            ],
            "masteries" : [{
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4211
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4212
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4221
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4222
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4232
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4233
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4312
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4313
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4314
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4322
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4324
                }, {
                    "rank" : 3,
                    "masteryId" : 4331
                }, {
                    "rank" : 2,
                    "masteryId" : 4333
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4334
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4341
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4342
                }, {
                    "rank" : 1,
                    "masteryId" : 4352
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "observers" : {
        "encryptionKey" : "dkGJf37jaGpYGYBhwbBaNcG9XvUKW9WQ"
    },
    "platformId" : "BR1",
    "bannedChampions" : [{
            "championId" : 64,
            "teamId" : 100,
            "pickTurn" : 1
        }, {
            "championId" : 238,
            "teamId" : 200,
            "pickTurn" : 2
        }, {
            "championId" : 40,
            "teamId" : 100,
            "pickTurn" : 3
        }, {
            "championId" : 103,
            "teamId" : 200,
            "pickTurn" : 4
        }, {
            "championId" : 268,
            "teamId" : 100,
            "pickTurn" : 5
        }, {
            "championId" : 55,
            "teamId" : 200,
            "pickTurn" : 6
        }
    ],
    "gameStartTime" : 1423276435804,
    "gameLength" : -126
}
```

and I need to get all of them, but now they come all in one variable ("wtfbo").

```
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  Map json1 = (Map) parser.parse(matei);
  JSONObject wtf1 = (JSONObject) json1;
  Long kiwi = (Long) wtf1.get("gameQueueConfigId");
  JSONArray eat = (JSONArray) wtf1.get("participants");
  Iterator<?> it = eat.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
      JSONObject dash = (JSONObject) it.next();

      Long wtfbo = (Long) dash.get("summonerId");

      System.out.println(wtfbo);
  }
```

When i run that, he returns (Note that these values are in a single Long variable "wtfbo")

```
2833743
2883696
1356728
653768
633003
458902
1513707
531086
891096
2982516
```

But I need that each comes in a string / variable separated. Using other words, i need that

```
Long a = 2833743
Long b = 2883696
Long c = 1356728
Long d = 653768
Long e = 633003
Long f = 458902
Long g = 1513707
Long h = 531086
Long i = 891096
Long j = 2982516
```

Ps: Sorry for bad english

Comment: Store them in a collection. You're going about this the (typical) wrong way.

Comment: How do you want to access them? By the order they occur in the JSON ? or by some other ID?

Comment: Note for understanding: These values do not all exist in a single Long variable at once. One of these values is ever in the variable at once and is overwritten by a new single value on the next loop iteration. That being said, the suggestions to use a Collection here would be your best course of action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to deal with an arbitrary number, you need to use a Collection. You've not stated any particular requirements, so I'm assuming you just want to access them in the order they occur in the JSON.

```
List<Long> summonerIds = new ArrayList<Long>(); // <== list to store summonerIds
while (it.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject dash = (JSONObject) it.next();
    summonerIds.add((Long) dash.get("summonerId")); // <== save 
}

System.out.println(summonerIds.get(0)); // 1st   <== access later
System.out.println(summonerIds.get(2)); // 3rd etc.
```

If you really need to access by "a", "b" etc, you can achieve this with a Map

```
Map<String, Long> summonerIds = new HashMap<String, Long>();
int i = 0;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject dash = (JSONObject) it.next();
    summonerIds.put(Character.toString((char) ('a' + i)), (Long) dash.get("summonerId"));
}

System.out.println(summonerIds.get("a")); // 1st
System.out.println(summonerIds.get("c")); // 3rd etc.
```